# reading from a file lines and numbers in c++

Tags: c++

I'm new in c++ and I'm practicing how to read from a file a string line one and then a number then a string line two.

example string

```
line one, number, string line two.
```

can someone help me to create a while loop, I know how to open a file. just need help reading a line of strings follow by reading in a number and a string line again.

```
while (?? file >> strline) {
   cout << strline;
   cout << number;
   cout << strline;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to tackle this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, all those people who have answered similar questions can help you.  Search StackOverflow for "c++ read file array text"

Comment: thanks Thomas Matthews, the questions are responded with c and I'm not using arrays. But thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can just read line by line, using `std::getline`

```
string strline;
while(getline(file, strline))
{
    cout << strline;
}
```

If you need the actual value of the number, can use a `std::istringstream` (must `#include <sstream>`), like

```
string strline;
if(getline(file,strline))
{
   // do something with the first line
}

if(getline(file,strline))  // read the second line
{    
    istringstream ss(strline);
    double x;
    ss >> x; // dump the number into x
}

if(getline(file, strline)) 
{
    // finally read the third line
}
```

Or, of course, can use a `for` like

```
string strline;
int x;
for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
{
    istringstream ss;
    if(getline(file, strline))
    {
        if(i == 1) // second line
        {
            // do something here with ss, like
            ss >> x; // dump the number into x
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi vsoftco, thanks for your fast reply. Yes I do need the value for number. what is the stringstream use for? Is to clear the buffer.

Comment: using `istringstream` is in a sense similar to reading from from a stream. You can use it to manipulate strings so they becomes in a sense equivalent to streams. Each line in your case gets transformed into a `istringstream`, then you can use the latter to effectively dump the values into the variables of need. See http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/95826-stringstream-tutorial/ for a tutorial. They are EXTREMELY useful for when you have more than one value per line.

Comment: Thanks! vsoftco, I'll keep working at it with your istringstream suggestion. Awsome!

Answer (score 0):

while(file)
 {
 getline(file,strline);     //reads inside a file
 cout << strline << endl;   // prints everything in the file

}